# How to convert wchar_t to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have wchar_t buffer [100] . Sometimes it needed for Unicode letters, sometimes is not.

I need to convert it to NSString.

I'm using  `NSString *str = [NSString string:(char *)buffer];` to conver it.

When I'm trying to NSLog my NSString, sometimes it getting right result, but sometimes is not.

Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything is as Totumus Maximus has said, but additionally you need to know how the characters in your buffer are encoded.  As `wchar_t` is 32 bits you probably have some 32 bit encoding of which UTF32-LE is the most likely.  What you want to do to get your NSString is:

```
NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: (const void*)buffer 
                                            length: sizeof(wchar_t) * numberOfCharsInBuffer
                                          encoding: someEncoding];
```

where:

- `numberOfCharsInBuffer` is the number of `wchar_t`s in the buffer that you want to decode.  The method above does not assume that the string is null terminated and will happily try to put nulls into the NSString if they appear before the length you specify (note that with wchar_t "null" means a 32 bit value that is zero).
- `someEncoding` is the [encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW59) used by the string in the buffer.  Try `NSUTF32StringEncoding`, `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding`.

Comment: As pointed out, and worth stressing, NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding is likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 16):

**My converter for "char", "wchar_t", "NSString". Use and enjoy.**

```
//-=(W)=-

+(NSString *)stringFromChar:(const char *)charText
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:charText];
}

+(const char *)charFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

+(NSString *)stringFromWchar:(const wchar_t *)charText
{
    //used ARC
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:charText length:wcslen(charText)*sizeof(*charText) encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
}

+(const char /*wchar_t*/ *)wcharFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    return  [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Why does `wcharFromString` return `const char *` instead of `const wchar_t *`?

Comment: @user1351086 I think the correct implementation of `wcharFromString` would be `+(const wchar_t *)wcharFromString:(NSString *)string { return  (const wchar_t *)[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]; }`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will clear things up.

C89 introduced a new integer type, `wchar_t`. This is similar to a char, but typically "wider". On many systems, including Windows, a `wchar_t` is 16 bits. This is typical of systems that implemented their Unicode support using earlier versions of the Unicode standard, which originally defined fewer than 65,535 characters. Unicode was later expanded to support historical and special purpose character sets, so on some systems, including Mac OS X and iOS, the `wchar_t` type is 32 bits in size. This is often poorly documented, but you can use a simple test like this to find out:

```
// how big is wchar_t?
NSLog(@"wchar_t is %u bits wide", 8 * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

On a Mac or iPhone, this will print "wchar_t is 32 bits wide". Additionally, `wchar_t` is a typedef for another integer type in C. In C++, `wchar_t` is a built-in integer type. In practice, this means you need to #include  in C when using wide characters.

Ref: http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-wide-character.html