# Convert wchar_t to CFStringref

Tags: c, macos

I have a `wchar_t *` that I need to use on a function that needs a `CFStringref`

I tried using `CFStringCreateWithCharacters` but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

So, if I have:

```
wchar_t * widecharvar = L"some value";
CFStringRef stringref;
```

How do I convert and copy `widecharvar` to `stringref`? This value will be used in `SecRequirementCreateWithString()`

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753262/how-to-convert-wchar-t-to-nsstring

Comment: Thanks, however I can't use that in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm doing this off the top of my head and memory; if it has trouble, comment and I'll actually test it.

```
// Check our byte order. Assuming we made the string as in your example
CFStringEncoding encoding = (CFByteOrderLittleEndian == CFByteOrderGetCurrent()) ? 
                              kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE : kCFStringEncodingUTF32BE;

int widecharvarLen = wcslen(widecharvar); 

CFStringRef string = CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL, 
                                             widecharvar, 
                                             (widecharvarLen * sizeof(wchar_t)),  
                                             encoding,
                                             false);
```

That last `false` means that string does not include a BOM (Byte Order Mark), which is the kind of string I assume you're dealing with.