# char, wchar_t and unichar

Tags: objective-c, unichar

I'm writing my first ever Objective-C/Cocoa program. (I already know C and C++ in the Windows world, i.e. Visual C++.) It looks like Cocoa can work with the `char` type, but prefers the `unichar` type. It also looks like Cocoa does NOT much care for wchar_t. So what type should I use for the C portion of my code, e.g. in structs?  If the answer is `unichar` then what are the equivalents of `const wchar_t* myString = L"this is my wchar string";`, `wcslcpy`, etc.?

Comment: There's nothing to stop you using NSStrings in structs

Comment: (but don't forget to call `release` when you're done with it!)

Comment: @Dave actually, in ARC there is (compiler warnings and the such). If he's using a C++ struct, then there's no problem though.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII because ARC can't guarantee the memory management for it.  You can use __unsafe_unretained objects in structs freely.

Comment: ah ok. I've only ever used Objective C with C++, and assumed the same principles applied to C.

Comment: @Dave the need to use special syntax and the need to call `release` are the very reasons I do not want to use NSString in a struct. I want to allocate the struct with `malloc` and deallocate the struct with `free`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides unfamiliarity, is there any reason why you aren't talking about NSStrings?

NSStrings are the standard string types in Objective C.  Unless you're trying to build some cross compiling C++ library into an iOS / Macintosh app, there probably isn't much reason to cling to a C-type.

[Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753262/how-to-convert-wchar-t-to-nsstring) that also includes further information and somebody's super useful looking set of methods that convert wchar_t into a NSString object and vice versa.