# what does this return parameter means?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
+(const char /*wchar_t*/ *)wcharFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    return  [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Does it return char or wchar_t?

from the method name, it should return wchar_t, but why there is a comment around wchar_t return type?

Source is here:

[How to convert wchar_t to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753262/how-to-convert-wchar-t-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code just looks incorrect. They're claiming it does one thing, but it actually does another. The return type is const char *.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not correct. It returns a `const char *`, encoded as a UTF8 string. That is a perfectly sensible way of getting a C string from an NSString, but nowhere here is anyone actually doing anything with `wchar_t`s.

`wchar_t` is a "wide char", and a pointer to it would be a "wide string" (represented by `const wchar_t *`). These are designed to precisely represent larger character sets, and can be two-byte wide character strings; they use a whole different variant set of string manipulation functions to do things with them. (Strings like this are very rarely seen in iOS development, for what it's worth.)